# getting only the tag name , not getting the text using python beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

below is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {"User-Agents":"googleBoat"}
r = requests.get('https://www.iiaonline.in/memberdetail.aspx?memid=11520',headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')

company_name = soup.find('span',{"id":"unit"})
print(company_name.text)
```

plz help me someone

Comment: the only spans with `id:unit` are blank.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. For questions of the "why is this code not working" type, you are supposed to post a minimal, _complete_, verifiable example (cf https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - in this case, it should have included either the content of `r.text` - or at least an abridged version of it reproducing the problem. By doing so, you would probably have found out that the relevant part of the markup in `r.text` was indeed empty and that the cause of the issue was with the page using js to load content.

Answer (score 1):

The page is dynamic.

**OPTION 1:**

Use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'https://www.iiaonline.in/memberdetail.aspx?memid=11520'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

r = browser.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')

company_name = soup.find('span',{"id":"unit"})
print(company_name.text)

browser.close()
```

**Output:**

```
print(company_name.text)
Anagram Development & Farmer Producer Co. Ltd.
```

**OPTION 2:**

Use the package [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) 
It appears it can grab some text that’s rendered by JavaScript, but I've never used it as it conflicts with jupyter Notebooks and Spyder which I use regularly, so I get errors (and I've been fine with using Selenium in the past). So you'd be on your own to try that, but below is an example from the docs.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()

r = session.get('http://python-requests.org/')

r.html.render()

r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']
```

**Output:**

```
'<time>25</time>'
```